I am running a job called sqltodb in data migration through batch file where I am running a query and storing that data into a database table
INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.2.1
24/06/12 03:24:58 WARN SparkConf: Note that spark.local.dir will be overridden by the value set by theanger (VI SPARK LOCAL DIRS in mesos/standalone/kubernetes and LOCAL DIRS in YARN).
24/06/12
03:24:58 INFO ResourceUtils: =====---------------
24/06/12
03:24:58 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.driver.
24/05/12 03:24:58
INFO ResourceUtils;===-----------------
24/06/12 03:24:58 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: smd
24/06/12 03:24:58 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(cores-> name: cores, amount: 1, script:, vendors, memory name: memory
amount: 8192, script:, vendor: offHeap -> name: offHeap, amount: 0, script:, vendors), task resources: Map(cpus-> name: cpus, amount: 1.8) 24/06/12 03:24:58 INFO ResourceProfile: Limiting resource is cpu
24/06/12 03:24:58 INFO Resource ProfileManager: Added
ResourceProfile id: 0 03:24:58 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acis to: gundu.sravya
24/06/12
03:24:58 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: gundu.sravya
24/06/12
24/06/12 03:24:58 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acis groups to: 24/06/12 03:24:58 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acis groups to:
24/06/12 03:24:58 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acis enabled; users with view permissions: Set(gundu.sravya); groups with view permiss
ions: Set(); users 24/06/12 03:24:59 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 63284.
with modify permissions: Set(gundu.sravya); groups with modify permissions: Set()
24/06/12 03:24:59 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker 24/06/12 03:24:59 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
24/06/12 03:24:59 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
03:24:59 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
24/06/12 24/06/12 03:24:59 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMasterHeartbeat
03:24:59 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at C:\Users\gundu.sravya\Documents\DataMigration\tmp\blockmgr-19164090-0097-4af3-a149-6d86c9falas
24/06/12 24/06/12 03:24:59 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 7.3 GiB
24/06/12 03:24:59 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
24/06/12 03:24:59 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040. 24/06/12 03:24:59 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to
0.0.0.0, and started at http://SMD-AZ3-SSBIAP1.spectramd.com:4040 24/06/12 03:24:59 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host SMD-AZ3-SSBIAP1.spectramd.com
24/06/12
03:24:59 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 63327.
24/06/12 03:24:59 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on SIMD-AZ3-SSBIAP1.spectramd.com:63327 03:24:59 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage. RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
24/06/12
24/06/12 03:24:59 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, SMD-AZ3-SSBIAP1.spectramd.com, 63327, None)
24/06/12 03:24:59 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager SID-AZ3-SSBIAP1.spectramd.com:63327 with 7.3 GiB RAM,
ectrand.com, 63327, None) 24/06/12 03:24:59 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, SMD-AZ3-SSBIAP1.spectramd.com, 63327, None) Go to Settings to activate Windows
24/06/12 03:25:00 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
24/06/12 03:24:59 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, SMD-AZ3-SSBIAP1.spectramd.com, 63327, None)
I have tried grant query in Ms sql but it's not working.
I want to insert data into database table.
Given arguments as
java -jar dist/Data migration.jar clientid=smd jobsubtype=sqltodb sqlquery="mypath'" output="tablename"

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
